# Javadoc never showing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Whenever I try to access the Javadoc for any class in Eclipse by hovering over a reference to it, it either says `An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc` or `This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc`. I've read through several solutions on StackOverflow and have tried them all including:

- Installing JDK and adding it as a library in my project.
- Verifying the source of Javadoc in rt.jar is the correct URL. When I click `Validate` on it it even says the location is likely valid.

The weird thing is, if I click on `View Javadoc in Browser` it opens directly to the correct Javadoc.

[image: Log File from my latest session in Eclipse]
[image: Both Libraries in Project]
[image: Location is Likely Valid.]

Comment: @Tom Thank you! That worked. I appreciate the help. Any idea why the JRE Javadoc randomly stopped working? It's worked fine for months.

Comment: As far as I know, the JREs do not contain JavaDoc. Maybe you've attached it manually and this was lost after an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the exception message, Eclipse is currently using the `JRE` instead of the `JDK`, since it is set up as the primary one (according to the second screenshot). Remove the `JRE library` from the project, you don't need it anymore. The `JDK` contains everything you need, including the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

Windows->Preferences -> Installed JRE -> click on the JDK ->JRE Deifination will open -> In RT.JAR attach java source as shown below:

[image]